# UI freezes while File-Download with WebClient

Tags: c#, download, webclient

I'm trying to download some files with the WebClient.DownloadFileAsync-Method.
It works fine as long as the UI istn't shown.

The UI is a Form with a Label and a ProgressBar on it.

In the DownloadProgressChanged-Event i want to show the current progress.
In order to do this i call a method with an int-parameter.
These are the methods for downloading:

```
private void DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if(progressDialog!=null){
        progressDialog.setFileProgress(e.ProgressPercentage);
    }
    Trace.WriteLine(String.Format("downloaded {0} of {1} bytes. {2} % complete...", 
        e.BytesReceived, 
        e.TotalBytesToReceive,
        e.ProgressPercentage));
}


private void DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{               
    if(progressDialog!=null){               
        progressDialog.setFileProgress(100);
    }
    are.Set();
}


private AutoResetEvent are = new AutoResetEvent(false);
public void DownloadFiles(List<DownloadObject> objects){
    Trace.WriteLine("Start Download");
    wc.DownloadProgressChanged += DownloadProgressChanged;
    wc.DownloadFileCompleted += DownloadFileCompleted;
    try{ 
        foreach(DownloadObject dlo in objects){                 
            currentFile = dlo;
            String url = dlo.DownloadURL;
            String path = dlo.LocalPath;
            Uri uri = new Uri(url);
            //GET
            Thread thread = new Thread(() => wc.DownloadFileAsync(uri,path));
            //thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            thread.Start();                 
            are.WaitOne();
            DeleteFile(dlo.ID);
        }               
        Trace.WriteLine("FileDownload finished");
    }catch(Exception ex){
        Trace.WriteLine("FileDownload failed: "+ex.Message);
    }finally{
        wc.Dispose();   
    }           
}
```

These are the relevant methodsinside the ProgressDialog-Form:

```
public delegate void dummy();
public void setFileProgress(int progress){          
    if(prgFile.InvokeRequired){
        Trace.WriteLine("Invoke required");
        prgFile.Invoke(new dummy(() => prgFile.Value = progress));
    }else{              
        Trace.WriteLine("Invoke not required");             
        prgFile.Value = progress;
    }           
}

public static ProgressDialog getInstance(IWin32Window owner){
    ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog();
    //pd.Show(owner); //
    return pd;
}
```

Now what happens is this: 
If pd.Show() is not called everything is just fine. The Progress gets changed and i get the Output "Invoke not required" as well as every step of the download.

However if the pd.Show() is called, i get the Output "Invoke required" multiple times without any download messages between.

So i debugged through that part of the code and it seems that progressDialog.setFileProgress() gets called but the DownloadProgressChanged-Event fires again directly after the prgFile.Invoke-method is called.

If i switch the Invoke-call to BeginInvoke, i get all the correct Messages again, but the ProgressDialog freezes until all downloads are finished and i don't get any progress shown.

What am i missing there? I read through tons of questions and threads about this but can't get it running.

I'm using SharpDevelop with .Net-Framework 4.0

Answer (score 0):

Because your 'DownloadFiles' method is synchronous, which blocks the UI thread. You start a new thread to download the file but

```
are.WaitOne();
```

blocks the current thread (the UI thread) until `are` is set (in the download completed event).

The correct solution is put those work after downloading (e.g. DeleteFile) in the complete event.

Comment: The problem is, that the DeleteFile-method deletes the fIle on the server. So if the DownloadFileAsync isn't finished yet i may get a problem. Also i need to use Asnyc since i won't get progress-information without it, but need to wait before i delete the file. how can i achieve this without AutoResetEvent? If i don't wait for the download to finish, i get an error that the webclient can't download multiple files at the same time.

Comment: Somewhere i read that there should be a webclient for each file, but i think my ProgressDialog would explode if i do this.

Comment: Now i tried putting the Deletion into the complete event and it happened what i predicted. first i got the message that WebClient can't download multiple files at the same time. then i created a new webclient for each file which resulted in unblocking the ProgressDialog, however the progressbar looks like a disco ball. maybe i should rethink the ProgressDialog and show multiple files in a datagrid or something.

Comment: You can `await` an async method call.

Comment: i tried that. seems that you can't wait for void. it isn't a good solution but i solved it by using a flag and checking every 100ms if it is set by using Task.Delay(100)

Comment: you can, as long as the method itself is aynchronous.

Comment: @MartinWeber You can call `DeleteFile` in the download-completed event callback, that guarantees the completion of the download.

Answer (score 0):

Because the `DownloadFiles`-method is synchronous and is running in the UI thread. Therefore, if you execute the method, your UI thread will be blocked until the Method is finished.

There are two approaches about this:

**Multithreading**

Just letting the Method run in a different task will solve your UI-Freezing. However, as you mentioned, in your case this will be a horrible approach because you can not manipulate your UI cross-thread. If you want to make status updates you should not go for this.

**Async/Await**

The better approach here. Although it seems very simple, async/await is actually very hard to do right. There are lots of resources on the internet and I would suggest starting on [dotnetperls](http://www.dotnetperls.com/async), which is a detailed introduction into async/await. It will take some time but is definetly the best approach about this.